# query result grouping and user interface

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface

I have a database table as

```
course(id, name, duration);
subject (id, course_id, elective_id, name)
```

Sample data for subject table are:

```
1, 100, NULL, subject1
2, 100, NULL, subject2
3, 100, NULL, subject3
4, 100, 1, subject4
5, 100, 1, subject5
6, 100, 2, subject6
7, 100, 2, subject7
8, 100, 1, subject8
9, 100, 2, subject9
```

rows having NULL are core subjects and others are electives. I want to display the format in html as following...

```
<ul id="select">
    <li>subject1</li>
    <li>subject2</li>
    <li>subject3</li>

    <li>
        <ul id="elective1">
            <li>subject4</li>
            <li>subject5</li>
            <li>subject8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <ul id="elective2">
            <li>subject6</li>
            <li>subject7</li>
            <li>subject9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what i have tried that does not works:

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM subject ORDER BY elective_id ASC';
```

LOGIC :

```
<ul id="select">
foreach($resource as $field){
  if($field->elective_id == NULL){
     echo '<li>'.$field->name.'</li>';
  } else {
     echo '<li>';
     echo '<ul id="'.$field->elective_id.'">';
     echo '<li>'.$field->name.'</li>';
     echo '</ul>';
     echo '</li>';
  }
}
</ul>
```

Comment: I'll be that guy today to ask Did you try anything yet on your own?

Comment: @peterm i have updated my question, can you please do me a favour?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky now the issue is that i can't display the elective subjects under the same ul sublists for same elective_id.